# Python - extract certain values from GeoJSON

Tags: python, csv, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file containing over 46,000 features, but I am only looking to extract 60 of them. The 60 features have a reference number which has been saved as CSV (see pic below for format of CSV)

E.g. of GeoJSON format

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "entities",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "Ref02-B", "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline", "EntityHandle": "18D49" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ etc ] ]
]
}
```

The python code below works, but is extracting any feature which has a digit for the layer name.
So for example, a layer `0` is being extracted.
How can I specify that it only picks out the layer name if it contains `Ref` and 2 digits?

E.g. `Ref01`

```
import json
import csv

with open('THE_CSV.csv') as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(cr)
    ref_column = header.index('Ref')  # column name
    references = [(row[ref_column]) for row in cr]

with open('THE_GEOJSON.geojson') as f:
    geo_json = json.load(f)

geo_json['features'] = [
    feature for feature in geo_json['features']
    if (feature['properties']['Layer'][3:4]) in references #looking for refs named Ref01 to Ref60
]

with open('OUTPUT.geojson', 'w') as f: #writing out to file to check output
   json.dump(geo_json, f)
```

[CSV snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Orl.png)

Comment: ... `and feature['properties']['Layer'].startswith('Ref')`?

Comment: Yes the ones I'm wanting to extract do

Comment: Okay, then use this expression in the `if` condition.

Comment: @mkrieger1 apologies, i thought you were asking a question! That's worked perfectly - thanks!